# File shredding not working properly (the shredded file is not the same size as the original)

Tags: python, file, byte, file-writing

I've been trying to make a file shredder that will overwrite every single byte of any file by a new random one, rename it, and then delete it. I disabled the deletion to check what the output was being like, and for some reason, the output file size was smaller than the original file size (exactly 1 byte of size). Before this happened, it was actually getting bigger that the original file size. I've been messing around with the code for some hours, but have not spot the mistake yet. What is causing it to be smaller?

```
def shred_file(path : str, passes : int, max_filename : int):
    global dir_char
    valid_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    valid_bytes = [ b"%c" %byte for byte in range(0x0, 0xFF+1)]
    filename_len = range(1, max_filename + 1)
    if(os.path.isfile(path) == True):
        filesize = os.path.getsize(path)
        for temp in range(0, passes):
            file = open(path, "wb")
            #Overwrite bytes
            for i in range(0, filesize + 1):
                file.seek(i)
                file.write(b"%c" %random.choice(valid_bytes))
            file.close()

            #Rename file
            new_name = str("".join(random.choices(valid_chars, k=random.choice(filename_len))))
            new_path = ""
            if(len(path.split(f"{dir_char}")) > 1):
                new_path = f"{dir_char}".join(path.split(f"{dir_char}")[0:-1]) + f"{dir_char}{new_name}"
            else:
                new_path = f"{dir_char}".join(path.split(f"{dir_char}")[0:-1]) + f"{new_name}"
            os.rename(path, new_path)
            path = new_path
        #os.remove(path)
```

Comment: As an aside, writes to the file likely went to different sectors than the original file. You aren't really erasing the data. You need file system aware tools to do that.

Comment: @tdelaney It must be possible to overwrite data on disk using only an open filehandle or I can't see how GNU shred (that can similarly be run as non-root without direct access to the raw block device) could operate. Though the file probably wants to be opened in `rb+` mode rather than `wb`.

Comment: Looking in `strace`, `shred` uses `O_WRONLY|O_NOCTTY`. None of the python `open` modes do exactly that, although `rb+` does `O_RDWR`. Both `wb` and `wb+` involve `O_TRUNC`, which I guess could lead to data being written elsewhere on disk. `O_RDWR` is probably adequate, though of course `os.open` could be used to force the exact same mode used by `shred`.

Comment: To the OP: the one byte extra was because of your loop `range(0, filesize + 1)`. You should just do `range(filesize)` for `filesize` iterations (values from `0` to `filesize - 1`).

Comment: Also to OP: I am not sure what `valid_bytes = [ b"%c" %byte for byte in range(0x0, 0xFF+1)]` does because `%` is not a valid operator for objects of type `bytes` in the version of python I'm using, but you should check the length of the items that you are writing. Hopefully they will be of length 1, in which case you also do not need the seek.

Comment: @alaniwi - From the shred man page: _CAUTION: Note that shred relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place._ Journalled file systems are more the rule than the exception these days. And media: SSD, RAID, SAN, NAS, Virtual Drives, these won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I changed the encoding to latin1 and it worked. Now the output file is the same size as the input:

```
def shred_file(path : str, passes : int, max_filename : int):
    print(f"[*] Current file: {path}")
    valid_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    valid_bytes = [chr(c) for c in range(0xFF+1)]
    raw_byte_encode = "latin1"
    filesize = os.path.getsize(path)
    if(os.path.isfile(path) == True and filesize > 0):
        for temp in range(passes):
            #Overwrite file with random raw bytes
            for i in range(filesize):
                fd = os.open(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_NOCTTY)
                os.pwrite(fd, random.choice(valid_bytes).encode(raw_byte_encode), i)
                os.close(fd)

            #Rename File
            new_name = "".join(random.choices(valid_chars, k=random.choice(range(1, max_filename + 1))))
            new_path = f"{dir_char}".join(path.split(f"{dir_char}")[0:-1]) + f"{dir_char}{new_name}"
            if(len(path.split(f"{dir_char}")) == 1):
                new_path = new_name
            os.rename(path, new_path)
            path = new_path

        #Remove file after completing all passes
        os.remove(path)
```

The entire code: https://github.com/rdbo/shredder.py .

Now that I fixed it, I wonder if this is a efficient way of shredding or could I do it better